# MongoDB Difference of 2 arrays

Tags: c#, mongodb

> Hi,
>
> Is it possible to get difference of 2 arrays in mongoDB.

```
  Collection1

    ID  Name
    1   Emp1
    2   Emp2
    3   Emp3


   Collection2

    ID  Name
    2   Emp2



   EmployeeDetails

    ID  Name
    1   Emp1
    3   Emp3

    EmpTransaction
```

> My question is it possible to get difference from collection1 and
>   collection2

```
db.EmployeeDetails.aggregrate(
{$match:  {"ID" : {"$in" : db.Collection1.distinct("ID",{"ID" ,db.EmpTransaction.distinct("ID",{"TranID" : 222})})
                                   SUBSTRACT            
               db.Collection2.distinct("ID",{"ID" ,db.EmpTransaction.distinct("ID",{"TranID" : 333})})}})
```

> As my data is huge i need to distribute the data in different document
>   and cant use Embedded Approach.
>
> Please let me know regarding it
>
> Thanks & Regards 
>   Ajay

Answer (score 0):

No. MongoDB does not do joins. Any single operation, be it a CRUD operation like `find()`, an aggregation pipeline, or a map/reduce, can only act on the documents of one collection and one collection only, possibly outputting the results to a new or existing collection.

If the data lives in multiple collections, you need to do application-level work and multiple MongoDB operations to combine.

What is your data like? How "huge" is it? Perhaps there is some way to use one collection with the proper data model.